# jQuery $.ajax won't pass array

Tags: ajax, arrays, jquery

I'm trying to pass an array like this using jQuery, but the PHP script never receives it and a look through Chrome's network trace shows that only `title` is passed.

```
var items = new Array();

items[0] = new Array();
items[0]['code'] = '1234';
items[0]['checked'] = true;

items[1] = new Array();
items[1]['code'] = '4524';
items[1]['checked'] = false;
```

This is the code that does the AJAX request:

```
var sUrl = "<?= base_url(); ?>list/create/";
var serialized = {
    title: 'Some Value Here',
    items: items
};
$.ajax({
    url: sUrl,
    type: "POST",
    data: serialized,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        list_id = data;
    }
});
```

The problem seems to be that jQuery can't serialize it. Is there any way around this? Thanks!

Comment: i think there might be something wrong w/how you're creating your `items` object

Comment: There are no associative arrays in javascript so you are indeed creating properties to the array.it wont serialize because you declared an array and not an bject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens when you create your items object like this:

```
var items = [
    {
        code: '1234'
        , checked: true
    }
    ,{
        code: '4568'
        , checked: false
    }
];
```

I think the problem is you're creating an array with your interior object when you should just be creating a standard object.

Comment: This is exactly what was happening. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you create an array and array cannot be indexed with string. If you must use string as index you should use object instead as provided in Jason's answer or:

```
items = new Array();

items[0] = new Object();
items[0]['code'] = '1234';
items[0]['checked'] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning a `new Array` to each index in `items`, but then you are assigning a new `code` and `checked` property to that array. This isn't serialized properly because rather than having an object at each position in the array, you have another array with some random properties (`code` and `checked`) that you've added.

Try assigning an object literal to each position in the array:

```
var items = [];

items[0] = {
    code: '1234',
    checked: true
};

items[1] = {
    code: '4524',
    checked: false
};
```